# How to Update View For new Data from Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    function getPlanetFeeds() {
       $("#planetFeedsDiv").load('/PlanetFeed/GetPlanetFeeds', function (data) {
       });

    var refreshPartial = setInterval(function () { getPlanetFeeds() }, 3000);
    function myStopFunction() {
       clearInterval(refreshPartial);
    }

 <div id="planetFeedsDiv">
 </div>
```

I am trying to get Feed from database when updated in it but the problem is that if i am uploading the video than it is getting refresh and not able to watch video continuously
if i am removing this function of time interval or increasing the time interval

```
var refreshPartial = setInterval(function () { getPlanetFeeds() }, 3000);
function myStopFunction() {
   clearInterval(refreshPartial);
}
```

than i am not able to get updated feed regularly

and i am getting the planetfeed from controller as follows

```
public ActionResult GetPlanetFeeds()
{
    var planetfeedsOrder = from a in db.PlanetFeeds
                            join c in db.Graphs
                            on a.PlanetFeedItemGraphId  equals c.GraphID
                            join u in db.UserInfos
                            on c.ItemUserID equals u.UserID
                            orderby a.PostDate descending
                           select new UserInfoViewModel
                           {
                               FirstName = u.FirstName,
                               LastName = u.LastName,
                               UserID = u.UserID,
                               AvatarURL = u.AvatarURL,
                               GraphItemDescription = c.GraphItemDescription,
                               GraphItemURL = c.GraphItemURL,
                               GraphID = c.GraphID,
                               ItemType = c.ItemType,
                               ItemUserID = c.ItemUserID,
                               GraphItemTitle = c.GraphItemTitle
                           } ;
    return PartialView("_PlanetFeeds", planetfeedsOrder.ToList());
}
```

Comment: What about the vide? I didn't got it! Are you uploading at the same time you are updating the feed?

Comment: @Fals i am uploading video from feed that is not in partial view when it get uploaded it is shown by partial view which is getting refresh as partial view is getting updating in a regular interval

Comment: you need to keep a flag saying that video has been uploaded on upload completed so that you can check your condition whether the video is uploaded or not. 

if(!IsVideoUploaded){ //reload; }

Comment: @Sravan News Feed is coming from partialview after if condition other feed will also not refresh so how can i use this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check count with old and update value by searching in database and call getPartial method when NewDataCount is greater than old data